# onTapImage in Html widget doesn't work (version 3.0.0-alpha.6)

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

[image]

On the package page it says I can use the 'onImageTap' argument to provide a function when an image is tapped in the Html widget.
Here it says that there is no such parameter.
Can you help me out, I really need newer version cause a lot of packages depend on it. I **can't** use **2.2.1** version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [Migration guide](https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/wiki/Migration-Guides) you will see that:

> onImageTap
> This parameter is removed. Instead, add the OnImageTapExtension:

```
Html(
  data: ...,
  extensions: [
    OnImageTapExtension(
      onImageTap: (src, imgAttributes, element) {
        // Handle an image being tapped
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```